# How to get data from the route url to put inside the callback function in React router?

Tags: reactjs, router

I'm working on my search feature. I want to trigger a callback function in the route to fetch all data before it goes into the search component.

Like this:

```
<Route path="/search/:query" component={QuestionSearchContainer} onChange={()=>store.dispatch(fetchData(query?)) }/>
```

here is the QuestionSearchContainer:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state,ownProps) => {
    return {
    questions: Object.values(state.entities.questions),
    currentUser: state.entities.users[state.session.id],
    query: ownProps.match.params.query, 
    url: ownProps.match.url 
}}
```

But how could I get the query keyword in the search url to put inside my fetchData as a parameter? I want to fetch the data and save it to the redux store before going to the QuestionSearchContainer so that I can get all data for questions in the container.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do the data fetching withing your QuestionSearchContainer component, you can make a higher-order component to wrap it with that does your data fetching for you.

You can easily modify this HOC to only return the Wrapped component when the data finishes loading as well. The loading part of this is assuming that fetchData is a [redux thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) action creator . [useParams](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/useparams) is a hook exported from react-router-dom that gives you access to the match params. [useDispatch](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch) is a hook exported from react-redux that gives you access to your store's dispatch function.

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const withFetchData = (Component) => ({ children, ...props }) => {
  const { query } = useParams();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    // Assuming fetchData is a a redux thunk action creator
    setLoading(true);

    dispatch(fetchData(query)).then(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    });
  }, [query]);
  if(loading){
    return 'loading...'
  }
  return <Component {...props} />;
};
const QuestionSearchContainerWithFetchData = withFetchData(
  QuestionSearchContainer
);

const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <Route
      path="/search/:query"
      component={QuestionSearchContainerWithFetchData}
    />
  );
};
```

Another option is to create a special route that does what you desire. For instance, this OnChangeRoute function would call the callback `onChangeParams` with the current params every time the params change. In this one, there's a loading prop that you have to pass in as the component itself doesn't care about what you are doing with the params.

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function InnerOnChangeRoute({ loading, onParamsChange, Component, ...rest }) {
  const onChangeRef = useRef(onParamsChange);
  useEffect(()=>{
    onChangeRef.current=onParamsChange;
  },[onParamsChange])
  useEffect(() => {
    onChangeRef.current(rest.match.params);
  }, [rest.match.params]);
  if(loading){
    return 'loading....'
  }
  return <Component {...rest} />;
}
// A wrapper for <Route> that redirects to the login
// screen if you're not yet authenticated.
function OnChangeRoute({ Component, onParamsChange, loading, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(data) => (
        <InnerOnChangeRoute
          Component={Component}
          onParamsChange={onParamsChange}
          loading={loading}
          {...data}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

In general for redux, you have to use dispatch (or mapDispatchToProps in the connector HOC) to run an action that updates the store with your data.

Here are some links that will hopefully help you get redux more under control.

https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#asynchronous-logic-and-data-fetching

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

Comment: but how I save the fetched data in the redux store? I want to fetch the data and save it to the redux store before going to the QuestionSearchContainer.

Comment: Also what's the useParams()? where it's defined?

Comment: I've updated both of my examples with some basic loading states and some links for redux. If you have trouble hooking these up to redux, I'd suggest making an effort at it and then making a new question if you can't figure it out. Stack overflow questions are meant to be more specific and focus on a single question rather than multiple

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `Route` doesn't have an `onChange` handler. (`onEnter` was available in previous versions(3 & earlier) of `react-router-dom`

Since your requirement seems to be specific to a single component(QuestionSearchContainer), using custom hooks or hocs may not be an ideal solution.

You can simply use a `useEffect` and listen to url changes(query). You can get the `query` using `props.match.params` and pass it as an argument to your dispatch callback.

Just make sure to maintain a `loading` state in redux and render a `fallback` while data is being fetched.

**code snippet**

```js
const QuestionSearchContainer = props => {
  ...
  useEffect(() => {
    const {query} = props.match.params
    console.log(query);
    store.dispatch(fetchData(query))
  }, [query]);
  ...
  return <div>      
      {!props.isLoading && <div>My actual question search component with data !</div>}
</div>;
};

export default QuestionSearchContainer;
```

Comment: I thought there is a way to fetch data in the router by triggering the callback function fetchData. Because I want to get all the data from database and save it in the frontend redux store before going to the QuestionSearchContainer.

Comment: no earlier we had `onEnter`. Now docs suggests to handle it ourselves inside component..

Comment: I see. Because there is a delay for the data transferred from the database that's why I'm trying to see if there is any way to fetch all data before going to the container.